# How do I to use Google Speech to Text in any Windows application?

Tags: windows, speech-to-text

When using Android, using the Swiftkey keyboard, I can use the Google Speech to Text anywhere, simply quickly holding a key. In my Windows PC, I want speak with the microphone and let Google type for me. I know that I can, using Chrome, in certain Google pages like "Language Tools" use this and then copy and paste in the target application. Is there an automatic way to do this?

Comment: You may want to check out https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Well google docs now has voice dictation if that is what you are after. Details [here](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/4492226?hl=en) you would still have to copy/paste into other apps if you need the text there.

as far as using a "mic" button in any text field on the pc it is not possible afaik, you might be able to use the web speech api to make a web app that interacts with an external program, but it would be a very funky workaround and a bit of code. also if it was made and shared the api key would likely be pulled by google for abuse.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this will fit a system wide requirement, or even all across Chrome, however there is a handy voice-to-text Chrome addon called [Chrome VoiceNote](https://voicenote.in/) that is quite useful.

This addon can be run in its own tab, and provides a mic button to toggle when your microphone will be used for input. There are plenty of options too, like support for other languages etc.